# Serializing HttpContext object to store in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, serialization, httpcontext

We have a C# ASP.Net MVC website.  I would like to store everything contained in the `HttpContext.Current.Request` object in a table in SQL Server for later analysis.

I attempted serializing the object into a Byte Array, then storing it in a binary field in SQL Server, however the serializer won't serialize the `HttpContext` object since it is not marked `Serializable`.

Is there any way to mark a System.Web class as serializable?  Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: I guess.  I could just spend 2 or 3 days coding all the possible items out.  I could write a loop to get every individual piece of text out of the URL the client sends.  I could, but WHY?  The question is not CAN I do that, it is CAN I serialize HttpContext?

Comment: Don't forget about security. You might be storing data you don't want to keep, like form posted passwords.

Answer (score 1):

For production code, I don't believe you can change the serialization aspect of the HttpContext. If this is non-production you might try modifying the Assembly to insert the Serializable attribute (but that may need to be done on sub-classes too) using a tool like Reflector and some plug-ins.

What might be an easier option would be to use Reflection to enumerate all the public and private fields. You could convert simple types to their string representation and recurse on classes that are slightly more complicated. You might even be able to find a tool to do this, the idea would probably be referred to ask an Object Graph viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise against storing the entire request, there would be far too much noise.

Instead pick out the signal that you want.  That is log specifically what you are interested in, e.g. particular variables.

Comment: It's the noise I'm interested in.  The standard stuff is already logged.