# Write Object to XML (No parameterless constructor)

Tags: c#, xml

I wish to write an object of the type [HttpContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) to a xml-file. Searching SO I've found several examples using a [XMLSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

However due to the fact that HttpContext doesn't have a parameterless constructor, i can't use a XMLSerializer.

Is there a way around this? Or is there another way to write an object to an xml-file?

Current Code:

```
    public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        DavEngineAsync engine = getOrInitializeEngine(context);

        context.Response.BufferOutput = false;
        DavContext ntfsDavContext = new DavContext(context);

        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer =
            new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(HttpContext));

        Guid myG = Guid.NewGuid();

        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "//" + myG.ToString() + " .xml";
        System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(path);

        writer.Serialize(file, context);
        file.Close();

        await engine.RunAsync(ntfsDavContext);
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain why you need to serialize the `HttpContext`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858064/serializing-httpcontext-object-to-store-in-a-database

Comment: @JeffFoster Debugging purposes. It seems that in some specific cases an bug occurs in our WebDav-Solution. I wish to view the differences in the request between a succesfull call and a faulty call.

Comment: @BurakSARICA thnx for the post. Must looked over that one when searching.

Comment: Since you don't need to deserialize later, you might instead try serializing to JSON with [tag:json.net].